# How to write the Xpath for the json field having white space?

Tags: java, xpath, xpath-3.1

I want to write the xpath for a json field which is having white spaces in it.

```
[    
    {"name":"Ram", "emai ld":"ram@gmail.com", "age":23},    
    {"name":"Shyam", "email id":"shyam23@gmail.com", "age":28}
]
```

I tried as below to get the email id:

```
?1?email id
```

When I searched in open source I got to know this is not possible in Xpath 3.1. Xpath 4.0 supports the above as

```
?1?'email id'
```

Can somebody helps how I can use Xpath 4.0? Meaning any dependency that I need to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the string literal in parentheses:

```
?1?('email id')
```

Answer (score 1):

Or just call the map with  e.g. `?1('email id')`.

Comment: @mads-hansen, my reading of the grammar would consider my example being a dynamic function call https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-dynamic-function-invocation, not a parenthesized expression.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-lookup `[54]    KeySpecifier    ::=    NCName | IntegerLiteral | ParenthesizedExpr | "*" `

Comment: That is what Michael Kay has suggested with his example of e.g. `?1?('email id')`, mine is a dynamic function call where `('email id')` is the sole function argument.

Comment: doh, I missed that it was missing the `?`